# Symfony 4 Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependencies, code-injection, symfony4

I've got class like this,

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class LoginTools {

private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

and in Controller

```
$logTool = new LoginTools();
```

**Question**

Does autowire should pass `EntityManagerInterface` to `LoginTools` automatically?
Because when I call `LoginTools` class without passing the argument I get error

`Too few arguments to function App\Utils\LoginTools::__construct(), 0 passed exactly 1 expected`

With Regards,

Wiktor.

Comment: Is your class LoginTools a service? And what function are you calling? It looks like you call the constructor which you don't need to do.

Comment: @Dirk J. Faber
I think so, because when I execute in cmd `php bin/console debug:autowiring` `App\Utils\LoginTools` shows on top. I'm instantiating class `LoginTools` so constructor is fired in this process right? `$logTool = new LoginTools();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, `LoginTools` is a service. That means, that you mustn't create it in code, like you do, Symfony creates it for you and you have just to inject this service in controller instead of `EntityManagerInterface`.

The thing is that Symfony has DI container, it's purpose is creating services based on your configuration from `config/services.yaml` and then injecting them into other services' constructors/functions/properties. There's no magic, all this code, which creates your services and inject them into other services, is generated automatically and is saved into `var/cache` dir by Symfony, you can check it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive response :) so I misunderstood how actually that works(Magic) but now I get it.